# How to deploy Flask Web app in Production server from PyCharm

Tags: python, deployment, flask

I am new to Flask Web with Python. I developed a simple Flask with Pycharm. Now I want to deploy it on my college server. I remember when I develop php web app I used to copy it to www folder in var and run it from there.

Can someone explain me how do I deploy python web app in Linux production server.

Comment: There is a whole [*Deployment Options* chapter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/) in the Flask documentation. Did you read it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters . Since I used Pycharm I didnt do any configurations. I want to what configuration I need to do to deploy it on the server. Thanks I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to figure out what your server provides from its sysadmin. There are tens of ways to do this,  and all of them have different answers.

Given that you have used php on the system before, I'll assume you are using Apache httpd.

First, you would need to have a wsgi provider installed (e.g. mod_wsgi) , and then wire your application into the wsgi provider.

See the mod_wsgi page and flask docs for more information on how to precisely do this.

- https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/
- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/

Another option is to have python bring its own webserver and optionally have a proxy redirect / load balance.

Comment: This is the updated link to the flask documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/#deployment